# Batch script to find and delete registry keys and/or values

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have scoured the internet for a batch file to find and delete registry keys and/or values.  The closest thing I found here:
 [Deleting all registry keys containing or named "string" with Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150523/deleting-all-registry-keys-containing-or-named-string-with-batch).

However, I have created a regsitry key in `"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"`, called `"tasksche"`, updated the scripts `RegKey` and Search variables as such, then changed Action to Delete.  It never finds and deletes it.

I have tried other methods to work this out, but nothings working.

What I am trying to write is this:
Batch file reads a list of keys from a text file
Batch file scans the registry for those keys and/or values
Batch file deletes those keys.

Comment: Did you try `Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "tasksche" /F >Nul 2>&1`?

Comment: So you basically need a `for /f ...` to process the lines in your file and then call a routine to delete that key or value from the registry. If it's not in the registry, the deletion will fail, but who cares? Or do you need to search for value names across multiple keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a batch file with a single command line for this task:

```
@for %%I in ("tasksche" "Other Value" "One More Value") do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%%~I" /f 2>nul
```

The internal command **FOR** runs external command **REG** for each string specified in parentheses which deletes the registry value from specified registry key.

**REG** would output an error message if the value to delete or the registry key itself does not exist. But this error message written to **STDERR** is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it.

This single line batch file can be extended to read the registry values to delete from a text file and additionally output which registry value were found and successfully deleted.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "CreatedListFile="
set "ListFile=%TEMP%\ListFile.txt"

if not exist "%ListFile%" (
    set "CreatedListFile=1"
    (
        echo tasksche
        echo Other Value
        echo "One More Value"
    ) >"%ListFile%"
)

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%ListFile%") do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%%~I" /f 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 echo Deleted "%%~I" from HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
)

if defined CreatedListFile del "%ListFile%"
endlocal
```

Of course it is possible to run multiple `reg delete` in the command block executed by **FOR**. But please note that using `reg delete` for deletion of a value or key in `HKLM` requires administrative privileges, i.e. the batch file must be executed as administrator.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `for /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg delete /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) explaining `>` used to create the list file and `2>nul` used to suppress the error message.